# The return is not working (javascript)

Tags: javascript

The function is returning undefined why it's not returning the array length.even at the start of the code it's printing in the console but return is not working.

```
var resArr = [];
var p;

function persistence(num) {
    resArr.push(num);
    console.log(resArr);
    console.log(resArr.length);
    if (num > 10) {
        var v = 1;
        var x = num.toString();
        var arr = [];
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            arr.push(x.charAt(i));
        }
        console.log(arr);
        for (j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            var v = v * arr[j];
        }
        persistence(v);
    } else {
        return resArr.length - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: When the function goes into the `if` you recursively call it but you don't return the result

Comment: Strongly recommend using standard, consistent indentation -- for your own sake, and certainly for the sake of the people you're asking help from.

Comment: Please try indenting your code correctly, and it will be a lot easier to follow. Until you get a hang of it, try running through a tool such as http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning in all cases.

Change

```
persistence(v);
```

to

```
return persistence(v);
```